# Finding the right cluster methods based on data distribution

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

My record has 821050 rows and 18 columns. The rows represent different online users, the columns the browsing behavior of the users in an online shop. The column variables include shopping cart cancellations, number of items in the shopping cart, detailed view of items, product list/multi-item view, detailed search view, etc... Half of the variables are discrete, half are continuous.  8 of the variables are dummy variables. Based on the data set, I want to apply different hard and soft clustering methods and analyze the shopping cart abondonnement of my data set more precisely. With the help of descriptive statistics I have analyzed my data set and obtained the following results.

```
# 1. WKA_ohneJB <- read.csv("WKA_ohneJB_PCA.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors =   FALSE)

# 2. summary(WKA_ohneJB)

X            BASKETS_NZ         LOGONS            PIS             PIS_AP           PIS_DV       
Min.   :     1   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :  1.00   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   :  0.000  
1st Qu.:205263   1st Qu.: 1.000   1st Qu.:1.0000   1st Qu.:  9.00   1st Qu.: 0.000   1st Qu.:  0.000  
Median :410525   Median : 1.000   Median :1.0000   Median : 20.00   Median : 1.000   Median :  1.000  
Mean   :410525   Mean   : 1.023   Mean   :0.9471   Mean   : 31.11   Mean   : 1.783   Mean   :  4.554  
3rd Qu.:615786   3rd Qu.: 1.000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.: 41.00   3rd Qu.: 2.000   3rd Qu.:  5.000  
Max.   :821048   Max.   :49.000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :593.00   Max.   :71.000   Max.   :203.000  
PIS_PL           PIS_SDV         PIS_SHOPS          PIS_SR           QUANTITY           WKA        
Min.   :  0.000   Min.   :  0.00   Min.   :  0.00   Min.   :  0.000   Min.   :  1.00   Min.   :0.0000  
1st Qu.:  0.000   1st Qu.:  0.00   1st Qu.:  0.00   1st Qu.:  0.000   1st Qu.:  1.00   1st Qu.:0.0000  
Median :  0.000   Median :  0.00   Median :  2.00   Median :  0.000   Median :  2.00   Median :1.0000  
Mean   :  5.729   Mean   :  2.03   Mean   : 10.67   Mean   :  3.873   Mean   :  3.14   Mean   :0.6341  
3rd Qu.:  4.000   3rd Qu.:  2.00   3rd Qu.: 11.00   3rd Qu.:  4.000   3rd Qu.:  4.00   3rd Qu.:1.0000  
Max.   :315.000   Max.   :142.00   Max.   :405.00   Max.   :222.000   Max.   :143.00   Max.   :1.0000  
NEW_CUST         EXIST_CUST        WEB_CUST       MOBILE_CUST      TABLET_CUST     LOGON_CUST_STEP2
Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000  
1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:1.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000  
Median :0.00000   Median :1.0000   Median :0.0000   Median :0.0000   Median :0.0000   Median :0.0000  
Mean   :0.07822   Mean   :0.9218   Mean   :0.4704   Mean   :0.3935   Mean   :0.1361   Mean   :0.1743  
3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:0.0000   3rd Qu.:0.0000  
Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000
```

[image]

With the non-dummy variables it is noticeable that they have a right-skewed distribution. For the dummy variables, 5 have a right-skewed distribution and 3 have a left-skewed distribution.

I have also listed range and quantiles for the 9 non-dummies

```
# BASKETS_NZ 
range(WKA_ohneJB$BASKETS_NZ) # 0 49
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$BASKETS_NZ, 0.5) # 1
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$BASKETS_NZ, 0.25) # 1
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$BASKETS_NZ, 0.75) # 1

# PIS
range(WKA_ohneJB$PIS) #   1 593
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS, 0.25) # 9
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS, 0.5) # 20 
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS, 0.75) # 41

# PIS_AP
range(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_AP) #  0 71
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_AP, 0.25) # 0
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_AP, 0.5) # 1 
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_AP, 0.75) # 2

# PIS_DV
range(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_DV) #   0 203
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_DV, 0.25) # 0
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_DV, 0.5) # 1 
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_DV, 0.75) # 5

#PIS_PL
range(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_PL) #    0 315
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_PL, 0.25) # 0
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_PL, 0.5) # 0 
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_PL, 0.75) # 4

#PIS_SDV
range(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SDV) #   0 142
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SDV, 0.25) # 0
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SDV, 0.5) # 0 
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SDV, 0.75) # 2

# PIS_SHOPS
range(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SHOPS) #   0 405
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SHOPS, 0.25) # 0
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SHOPS, 0.5) # 2 
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SHOPS, 0.75) # 11

# PIS_SR
range(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SR) #   0 222
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SR, 0.25) # 0
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SR, 0.5) # 0 
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$PIS_SR, 0.75) # 4

# QUANTITY
range(WKA_ohneJB$QUANTITY) #   1 143
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$QUANTITY, 0.25) # 1
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$QUANTITY, 0.5) # 2 
quantile(WKA_ohneJB$QUANTITY, 0.75) # 4
```

> How can I recognize from the distribution of my data which cluster methods are suitable for mixed type clickstream data?

Comment: @ StupidWolf please can you tell me how to find the right cluster methods based on my data distribution?

Comment: hey @As123, unfortunately there's no such thing as right cluster method based on your distribution. Looking at your distribution, it looks like a lot of them are centered around 0, and the range is huge. You might want to take the log of them and plot first

Comment: After you convert them into something easier to work with, you can try kmeans or hclust. But note that your dataset is 821050 rows, which is huge. Sample like 100k lines  (sample(nrow(..),100e3) and try to move ahead